# How to obtain transparent animated gif via Export?

Tags: plotting, export, animation, opacity, gif-format

I have the following code to create animated GIFs:

```
ClearAll["`*"];
xmin = -3;
xmax = 4;
ymin = -10;
ymax = 3;
line1 = Line[{{xmin, ymin}, {xmin, ymax}}];
line2 = Line[{{xmax, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}}]; 
slides = 8; 
cmin = -10; 
cmax = 5/2; 
v = Table[Manipulate[
     Plot[{1/3 x^3 + x^2 + x - (2 x^2 + 4 x), c}, {x, xmin, xmax}, 
      PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, AspectRatio -> GoldenRatio, 
      PlotRange -> {{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}}, 
      Epilog -> {Directive[{Green, Green}], line1, line2}, 
      Background -> None], {{c, k/slides, "Constant:"}, cmin, cmax}],  
     {k, cmin*slides, cmax*slides}]; 
v = Join[v[[1 ;; Dimensions[v][[1]] - 1]], Reverse[v]];
```

When I use:

```
Export["testManip007.gif", v]
```

I obtained:

[image]

In order to get transparent background gif, I tried the following which worked for other cases:

```
Export["testManip007t.gif", v, "TransparentColor" -> White]
```

but the resulted is:

[image]

Additionally:

```
Export["testManip003t.gif", v, "DisplayDurations" -> 0.1, 
 "TransparentColor" -> White]
```

always causes error message and empty output.

How to solve the problems?

Comment: I tried setting `Background` explicitly to `White` but with no improvement to the exported gif.  I then set both `Background` and `"TransparentColor"` to `Yellow`, which improved the appearance of the slider but not the plot itself.

Comment: Setting `"Interlaced"` option to `True` or `False` does not have an effect.

Comment: You can't. Animations are realized through frames, i.e., the next frame appears through the former if you set `"TransparentColor" -> White`. My recommendation stay with white background.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Note for Version 11.1**: As [commented](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65970/how-to-obtain-transparent-animated-gif-via-export/77020?noredirect=1#comment404012_77020) by [LCFactorization](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/9851/lcfactorization) the option setting

```
"TransitionEffect" -> Background
```

is no longer working (error message + nothing exported).

The solution is to use `"TransitionEffect" -> "Background"` instead, which doesn't produce the desired result in version 10.4 and earlier.

---

By default the frames of a GIF are stacked on top of each other. One can change this behavior using the `Export` option `"TransitionEffect" -> Background`:

```
Export["testManip007t.gif", v, "TransparentColor" -> White, "TransitionEffect" -> Background]
```

> [image]

The default setting is `"TransitionEffect" -> None`.

Comment: Do you know what other `TransitionEffect` options are available? From `Import[#, {"GIF", {"TransitionEffect"}}] &` I have seen only `None`, `False` and `Background`.

Comment: @rhermans I didn't come across any other option values either. I'm also not aware of something else the GIF file specifications would provide. It's a relative simple file format and the Mathematica exporter is rather primitive.

Comment: This option seems no longer work in the latest version 11.1?

Comment: @LCFactorization You are correct, thanks for pointing that out. In version 11.1 you have to use `"Background"` instead of `Background` as the option value.

Comment: @Karsten7 It seems that this option no longer works in version 11.3, again. I've tried to find a solution for myself but I can't. Maybe you could use your skills again to solve this problem? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: @RoberRM I currently don't have version 11.3, but based on the change in the documentation I'd first check what the "DisposalOperation" of an exported gif is by default and then try setting it to "Background".

Comment: @Karsten7. You have a good eye (how do you find changes in the documentation?) Unfortunately, I have used the four options given in the documentation for "DisposalOperation" and the results are as if I did nothing. I have used them also without quotes, just in case, and the same happens. If you have more ideas I am willing and able to try them for the next few hours. If not, thank you for trying.

Comment: @Karsten7. Hello again! So, I contacted Wolfram Technical Support and they just confirmed that there is no way to export a GIF with a transparent background using the old `"TransitionEffect" -> Background` trick. They tell me they are "_looking to release a new version of Mathematica that has [the `"DisposalOperation"` option] included in the Export functionality_", but right now it only works for importing GIF files. So, I'll have to wait I guess, or maybe reinstall an older version of Mathematica. I'll keep you posted as soon as I learn anything new. And thank you for your help!

Comment: @RoberRM You can use GIMP to make the GIF you exported from Mathematica have a transparent color and be much more optimized.

Comment: @RoberRM Btw., what are the options of a GIF now (`Import["test.gif", "Options"]`)? Maybe something like `Export["test3.gif", plots, 
 "TransparentColor" -> 
  ConstantArray[RGBColor[1., 1., 1.], Length@plots], 
 "TransitionEffect" -> ConstantArray["Background", Length@plots]]` works.

Comment: @Karsten7. Of course! Just use GIMP! Why didn't I think of that solution!? You have saved me a lot of trouble. And I'll try the `ConstantArray` options as soon as I can, later today, and I'll let you know. Thank you very much for the GIMP workaround. I was obsessed trying to make it work just with Mathematica.

Comment: @Karsten7. Unfortunately, the `ConstantArray` approach doesn't work either. The options that appear in a GIF I created with `"DisposalOperations" -> "Background"` are: `"AnimationRepetitions" -> 1, "ColorSpace" -> RGBColor, "DisplayDurations" -> {...}, "DisposalOperation" -> {Missing["NotAvailable"], ...}, "ImageSize" -> {...,...}, "TransparentColor" -> {White, ...}`. (The `...` mean that there are a lot of numbers or repetitions in there, one for each key frame.) So it is true that even though I can see `"DisposalOperation"` when importing a GIF, I can't set it when exporting it.

Answer (score 2):

Since Mathematica still seems not to support transparent animated gifs, one can work around the problem by exporting ".png" files and using an external program to stitch them together into an animated gif.  For example:

```
ExportAsTransparentGIF[dir_, basefn_, frames_, ExportOptions___] := 
 Module[{b = 10, n, filename, filenames},
  n = 1 + Round@Log[b, Length[frames]];
  filenames = 
   Table[filename = dir <> basefn <> IntegerString[i, b, n] <> ".png";
     Export[filename, frames[[i]], Background -> None, 
     ExportOptions];
    filename, {i, Length[frames]}];
  command = 
   "/opt/homebrew/bin/convert -dispose 2 -set delay 0 " <> 
    StringRiffle[filenames] <> " " <> dir <> basefn <> 
    "animated.gif";
  Run[command];
  (* cleanup *) 
  command = "rm " <> StringRiffle[filenames];
  Run[command];
  ]
```

Here I am using the `convert` command from ImageMagick, installed on my mac with homebrew.

```
gTetra = Tetrahedron[];
Nt = 150;
frames = Table[t = (2. Pi) i/Nt;
   Show[Graphics3D[
     GeometricTransformation[gTetra, 
      RotationTransform[t, UnitVector[3, 3]]]], 
    Boxed -> False, SphericalRegion -> Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 0.7]], {i, 
    Nt}];

ExportAsTransparentGIF["~/png-repo/", "Tetra-spin-", frames];
```

[image]